# Recursive list of LINK_LIBRARIES in CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to acquire a list of the absolute paths to all libraries linked to a specific target in CMake for use in a call to `add_custom_command`. However, `get_target_property(_LINK_LIBRARIES ${TARGET} LINK_LIBRARIES` only includes the direct dependencies (i.e. anything that is used in a `target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ...)` call).

Therefore, if I link another CMake target, e.g. `mylibrary`, the list would include `mylibrary`, but as a name only and without transitively linked libraries. As this list can also include arbitrarily complex generator expressions, checking each item if it is a target and retrieving its `LINK_LIBRARIES` recursively is not viable. Furthermore the target could be specified at a later point in the `CMakeLists.txt` and `if(TARGET mylibrary)` would be skipped.

For `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` this is easily solved, as although both behave similarly when `get_target_property` is used (except that linked targets are obviously not in the list), a generator expression of the form `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${TARGET},INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>` produces the desired list of recursively required includes and definitions. However, `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${TARGET},LINK_LIBRARIES>` produces the same list as the `get_target_property` variant.

How can I retrieve the desired list of absolute paths?

Demonstration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12 FATAL_ERROR)

file(WRITE a.cpp "void foo() {};\n")
file(WRITE b.cpp "int main(int, char**) { return 0; }\n")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)

add_library(A STATIC a.cpp)
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

# demonstrates (at configure time) that the LINK_LIBRARIES property can contain
# arbitrary generator expressions, making a recursive solution infeasible
get_target_property(A_LINK_LIBRARIES A LINK_LIBRARIES)
message(STATUS "A LINK_LIBARIES: ${A_LINK_LIBRARIES}")

add_executable(B b.cpp b_lists)
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE A)
target_include_directories(B PRIVATE .)

get_target_property(B_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES B INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_target_property(B_LINK_LIBRARIES B LINK_LIBRARIES)

# demonstrates (at compile time) that method 1 is not recursive while method 2 is (for INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
# demonstrates (at compile time) that the library list is never recursive
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT b_lists
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "B INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 1: ${B_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "B INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 2: $<TARGET_PROPERTY:B,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "B LINK_LIBRARIES 1: ${B_LINK_LIBRARIES}"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "B LINK_LIBRARIES 2: $<TARGET_PROPERTY:B,LINK_LIBRARIES>"
    DEPENDS A
)
set_source_files_properties(b_lists PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC TRUE)
```

Output:

```
(configure)
A LINK_LIBARIES: $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:D:/libs/boost-1_55_0/lib/boost_filesystem-vc110-mt-1_55.lib>;$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:D:/libs/boost-1_55_0/lib/boost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib>;$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:D:/libs/boost-1_55_0/lib/boost_system-vc110-mt-1_55.lib>;$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:D:/libs/boost-1_55_0/lib/boost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib>
(build)
Generating b_lists
B INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 1: D:/projects/cmakeminimal/.
B INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 2: D:/projects/cmakeminimal/.;D:/libs/boost-1_55_0/include/boost-1_55
B LINK_LIBRARIES 1: A
B LINK_LIBRARIES 2: A
```

Comment: @usr1234567 please read the question properly as it already states the two approaches I have tried and why they do not work.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I wanted to see some code but it wouldn't help.

Comment: Yes, I could try making a minimal example but it didn't seem all that useful.

Comment: `checking each item if it is a target and retrieving its LINK_LIBRARIES recursively is not viable.` - Why checking each item is not vialable? As I understand, generator expressions are evaluated on build time, so them cannot be evaluated to target names, which are known only at configure time. `Furthermore the target could be specified at a later point in the CMakeLists.txt and if(TARGET mylibrary) would be skipped.` - All targets used in `target_link_libraries` should exist at the call time.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `cannot be evaluated to target names`, wrong, they absolutely can. try linking to `$<$<CONFIG:Release>:A>` in the minimal exampe. Furthermore, and the more serious issue, not all generator exprression are valid in `add_custom_command`. `should exist at the call time`, should, maybe, have to, definitely not. Move lines 8-15 of the example to the end of the file and observe how the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, you are right: generator expressions can express target name. Or, even *part* of the target name (e.g. `<$<$CONFIG:Debug>:A>A` is recognized as `AA` target for `Debug` configuration). So matching libraries to targets names would be very difficult thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your wish has been out there for a while and is - as far as I know - not yet (as for CMake 3.3.2) embedded into `CMake` itself (see [0012435: Possibility to get all link libraries for a target?](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/12435)).

I got some hope because this ticket lists a few possible alternative approaches. But after I tested those against your example `CMake` project I would say they are not really a solution:

1. [`export_library_dependencies()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/export_library_dependencies.html) - *Deprecated*

   Note: Because this works only for Lib-To-Lib dependencies I have - for this test - changed your `add_executable()` to an `add_library()` call

   ```
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0033 OLD)
   export_library_dependencies(LibToLibLinkDependencies.cmake)
   include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibToLibLinkDependencies.cmake")

   message("A_LIB_DEPENDS: ${A_LIB_DEPENDS}")
   message("B_LIB_DEPENDS: ${B_LIB_DEPENDS}")
   ```

   would give e.g.

   ```
   A_LIB_DEPENDS: optimized;../libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-1_53.lib;debug;../libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib;...
   B_LIB_DEPENDS: general;A;
   ```

   See also [policy CMP0033 "The export_library_dependencies() command should not be called"](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0033.html)
2. [`export(TARGETS ...)`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/export.html)

   ```
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0024 OLD)
   export(
       TARGETS A B
       FILE Test.cmake 
       NAMESPACE Imp_
   )
   include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Test.cmake")
   ```

   But this keeps the generator expressions in the output and you need add to the list all depending targets, so no good.

   See also [policy CMP0024 "Disallow include export result"](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0024.html).
3. [`GET_PREREQUISITES()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GetPrerequisites.html)

   I've taken the code from [how to use the cmake functions get_prerequisites and get_filename_component for target dependency installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367033/how-to-use-the-cmake-functions-get-prerequisites-and-get-filename-component-for), but it shows - as described in the module's documentation - that it lists only the *shared* libraries.

   ```
   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT b_lists
       APPEND
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D MY_BINARY_LOCATION="$<TARGET_FILE:B>" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ListSharedLibDependencies.cmake"
   )
   ```

   **ListSharedLibDependencies.cmake**

   ```
   include(GetPrerequisites)

   get_prerequisites(${MY_BINARY_LOCATION} DEPENDENCIES 0 0 "" "")

   foreach(DEPENDENCY_FILE ${DEPENDENCIES})
       gp_resolve_item("${MY_BINARY_LOCATION}" "${DEPENDENCY_FILE}" "" "" resolved_file)
       message("resolved_file='${resolved_file}'")
   endforeach()
   ```

   would output on my Windows machine:

   ```
   resolved_file='C:/Windows/SysWOW64/KERNEL32.dll'
   resolved_file='C:/Windows/SysWOW64/MSVCR110D.dll'
   ```

**References**

- [Retrieve all link flags in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165365/retreive-all-link-flags-in-cmake)
- [Get all source files a target depends on in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448892/get-all-source-files-a-target-depends-on-in-cmake)

Comment: The last approach also only works for dlls that are already found in the default paths as far as I can tell, making it even less useful. In fact on of my use cases is pre-filling the list of directories passed to `gp_resolve_items` with useful defaults.

Comment: Seeing that something so important is on the backlog is depressing.

Comment: And as "it's currently not possible" is apparently the answer I will accept this for now.

Comment: @Joe Yes, it could be depressing. Regarding your problem: would it be an option to put all the libraries and CMake outputs into defined (sub-)folder under binary outputs? Then you would know where to search for them (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742090/custom-directory-for-cmake-library-output), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120511/cmake-use-add-custom-command-to-copy-binary-to-specific-location-failed-when-lo) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414587/parent-cmakelists-txt-overwriting-child-cmakelists-txt-output-directory-options)).

Comment: No, the main problem is with external libraries, the internal ones are already installed/built in the correct location.

Comment: @Joe Just wanted to let you know that I found a solution for makefile targets (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165365/retreive-all-link-flags-in-cmake)). Something build-in would still be preferable, but maybe it helps.

Comment: @Joe Just wanted to let you know that [this issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/12435) just got revived. Maybe you want to add something to the [ongoing discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/cmake-developers@cmake.org/msg17419.html).

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't something like this a basic requirement for creating packages which other projects can find via find_package? What good is it to be able to create a package if I cannot tell client projects what libraries are required in order to link against mine? Or am I missing something here? Surely I can usefully create packages that have non-trivial external library dependencies...

Comment: @BenFarmer Packages will just define their link dependencies via the [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES) target property.

Answer (score 13):

Recursively traversing `LINK_LIBRARY` property is possible.

Here is a `get_link_libraries()` that does that, however it does not handle all cases (e.g. libraries not being a target, not imported libraries).

```
function(get_link_libraries OUTPUT_LIST TARGET)
    get_target_property(IMPORTED ${TARGET} IMPORTED)
    list(APPEND VISITED_TARGETS ${TARGET})
    if (IMPORTED)
        get_target_property(LIBS ${TARGET} INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
    else()
        get_target_property(LIBS ${TARGET} LINK_LIBRARIES)
    endif()
    set(LIB_FILES "")
    foreach(LIB ${LIBS})
        if (TARGET ${LIB})
            list(FIND VISITED_TARGETS ${LIB} VISITED)
            if (${VISITED} EQUAL -1)
                get_target_property(LIB_FILE ${LIB} LOCATION)
                get_link_libraries(LINK_LIB_FILES ${LIB})
                list(APPEND LIB_FILES ${LIB_FILE} ${LINK_LIB_FILES})
            endif()
        endif()
    endforeach()
    set(VISITED_TARGETS ${VISITED_TARGETS} PARENT_SCOPE)
    set(${OUTPUT_LIST} ${LIB_FILES} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Comment: Does not work if `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` contains a generator expressions
`$<$<CONFIG:Release>:CONAN_LIB::fmt_fmt_RELEASE;>` since its a list itself...