# How to get location of external libraries in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

I have a CMake project which build library with external dependencies:

```
add_library(lib_name ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(lib_name ${DEPENDENCIES})
```

${DEPENDENCIES} contains of dependencies which found by find_package().

After I want to install my library in package:

```
install(TARGETS lib_name DESTINATION lib COMPONENT package)
```

So, and I want to add all (recursive) dynamic dependencies (*.so) of lib_name to package. I know that CMake solve recursive dependencies when build library, but I don't know how to install it to package.
Maybe somebody know how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way is to put a call to find_package in the generated config script.

Comment: I'm not sure, that I understand you. Can you explain your idea? Thank!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive list of LINK\_LIBRARIES in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756195/recursive-list-of-link-libraries-in-cmake)

Comment: So, it's good point, but it not handle dependencies of external dependencies.

Comment: Personally, I did it by incorporating dependencies as CMake Subprojects (using ExternalProject) thus everything is exported but you need to recompile everything (and adapt each dependency to be used that way)...