# Automatically add linking options to dependants of shared lib

Tags: cmake, linker, linker-flags

Let's say I have a shared lib, `A`, and something else that links against it, `B`. They are in two *separate* projects.

In my current setup, for `A`'s functionality to be able to work properly, `B` needs to add `-rdynamic` to its linker options, like this:

```
target_link_libraries(B -rdynamic)
```

The thing is that there may be many, many dependants of `A`, so having to explicitly include the line above for each of them is a hassle.

Is there a way for `A` to have all its dependants automatically use `-rdynamic`?

---

**Edit**: here's a more detailed explanation of my situation.

I have a shared library, `mylib`. It *cannot* be a static library. It is defined in a CMake project of the same name.

```
mylib
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── ...
```

Its `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
# mylib/CMakeLists.txt
project(mylib)
...
add_library(mylib SHARED ${SOURCES})
...
```

In separate projects, there are executables, `client_i`, that use/link against `mylib`, sometimes indirectly (i.e. link against something that links against `mylib`).

```
client_0
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── ...
client_1
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── ...
client_2
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── ...
...
```

One of those `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
# client_i/CMakeLists.txt
project(client_i)
...
add_executable(client_i ${SOME_OTHER_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(client_i mylib -rdynamic)
...
```

Notice the `-rdynamic`. Without this option, some functionality provided by `mylib` doesn't work. I need it.

My problem is that there may be *thousands* of different `client_i`s, each defined in its own project by different people/users of `mylib`, which I provide (and may be used as a binary).

I'd like to avoid having to add `-rdynamic` to each of the `client_i`s, since some users might not know about it (since it may be used indirectly), some might forget about it, it might lead to headaches, etc.

Ideally, the `CMakeLists.txt` for `mylib` would look like:

```
# mylib/CMakeLists.txt
project(mylib)
...
add_library(mylib SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(mylib -rdynamic)
...
```

And a `client_i` `CMakeLists.txt` would simply be:

```
# client_i/CMakeLists.txt
project(client_i)
...
add_executable(client_i ${SOME_OTHER_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(client_i mylib)
...
```

And it would have `-rdynamic` in its linker options. But I have tried this and it does *not* seem to work.

Comment: Nowadays we have `target_link_options`. You can write a function that will get all dependent libraries of `A` (with like `get_target_properties(A LINK_DEPENDS ...)`) and apply `target_link_options` to each one of them.

Comment: You could loop over your list of dependents, only writing the `target_link_options(B -rdynamic)` line once.

Comment: @KamilCuk the version of CMake I have to use doesn't have `target_link_options` but I assume there's an alternative. I'm not sure how to get all dependants though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127212/9072753

Comment: `A` and `B` are in separate projects, though. `A` doesn't know about its dependants. I'm not sure I understand!

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Comment: @squareskittles `3.10.2`

Comment: I think I don't understand. Can you post some example pseudo-CMakeLists? If you have `add_library(B "")` and `target_link_libraries(B -rdynamic)` and you have `add_executable(A)` and `target_link_libraries(A B)`, then `A` will be linked with `-rdynamic` option. Because static libraries are not linked, they are just compressed, the link options interface is just passed up until executable is build. I don't know what you want. I believe your question, as now, is unclear, and should be closed. Can you add example project structure with CMakeLists and say, what you exactly want to achieve?.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to achieve, but like I mentioned in my question, it has to be a shared library. It cannot be a static library.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've added a more in-depth explanation, including details about the overall structure.

Comment: The configuration you literally posted works as you indent it to do. Did you at least try it? What is your question? Please create a full MCVE.

Comment: [This is an MCVE](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/stackoverflow-automatically-add-linking-options-to-dependants-of-shared-lib). The `-lm`  is only in [mylib/CmakeListst.txt](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/stackoverflow-automatically-add-linking-options-to-dependants-of-shared-lib/blob/master/mylib/CMakeLists.txt), but all the `client_x` libraries are linked against it, as can be seen [here](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/stackoverflow-automatically-add-linking-options-to-dependants-of-shared-lib/-/jobs/252433339) `cc ... CMakeFiles/client_2.dir/main.c.o  -o client_2  ...  -lm -rdynamic`

Comment: Note that in [here](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/stackoverflow-automatically-add-linking-options-to-dependants-of-shared-lib/-/jobs/252433339) when compiling clients the first `-rdynamic` option is auto-added by cmake from [Linux-GNU.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Linux-GNU.cmake#L14), because cmake auto-adds it with shared libraries. The last `-rdynamic` and `-lm` are added from `mylib` module, as intended. The case is more visible when inspecting `-lm` flag. `-lm` is added only in `mylib/CMakeLists`, yet clients link against it. Case closed.

Comment: My setup isn't 100% like the example I included (or your MVCE). It involves other things, so I guess my issue is somewhere in there. I don't know how to create a representative MVCE. Therefore I guess I have to close this question

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple solution you can try:

```
# Get a list of A's direct library dependencies.
get_target_properties(LIB_DEPENDENCIES A LINK_LIBRARIES)

# Loop through each library, adding the link option to each.
foreach(LIB ${LIB_DEPENDENCIES})
    target_compile_options(${LIB} PRIVATE "-rdynamic")
endforeach()
```

This can be expanded, similar to the answer @KamilCuk linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756195/recursive-list-of-link-libraries-in-cmake/39127212#39127212), to account for static/shared/imported libraries and recursion depending on the variety and complexity of your dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would fit in my use-case. `A` and `B` are in separate projects. Thus I can't do this in `A`'s `CMakeLists.txt`, since it simply cannot know about its dependants, right? Also this seems to loop over `A`'s dependencies, not its dependants.

Comment: Ah, dependants. I mis-understood your question. And yes, it would seem you would have to do this within the `CMakeLists.txt` for each dependant (e.g. `B`), or from your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: @christophebedard `since it simply cannot know about its dependants, right?` - but dependents know and they do this by default. So if you one of dependents will link against you, it's `LINK_LIBRARIES` will be populated using all dependencies `LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`. So, by default, it will work. What is your question then? I think you should read [cmake target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#command:target_link_libraries), it literally says: `Libraries for both a Target and its Dependents`

Comment: If you are looking for the dependencies of `A`, then yes, `LINK_LIBRARIES` should give you what you want. But if you want a list of libraries/executables that depend on `A` (dependants), I don't think you can use this approach. The cleanest approach may be to iterate through all the targets from the top-level CMake, checking the `LINK_LIBRARIES` of each to see if `A` is present, then conditionally adding the `-rdynamic` option if necessary. Just a guess though since we don't know the hierarchy of project structure...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've added more information about the project structure. It's really not monolithic. There's no top-level CMake project.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to link `A` against `B` when `A` and `B` are in different projects?

If `A` is a different project than `B`, the you have to [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/export.html) package `A` and use [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_package.html) in project `B` to find `A`. [Here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_package.html) is a good tutorial show-casing the use-case.