# Define compile definitions in library dependencies for multiple targets

Tags: cmake, dependencies

Is there a way to set compile definitions for a linked library target but with different sets of definitions for the library used by each target (compile defs are mutually exclusive for the lib linked with each target)?

```
Target A > lib with -DDEF_A only
Target B > lib with -DDEF_B only
```

`target_compile_definitions()` only allows you to set definitions on a target, but if set on the library target this would be set for both targets.

The only way I can think of doing it is to create a function to add new library targets, so multiple library targets can be defined with different compile definitions.

Comment: Every library target you create in CMake eventually produces **single** library file. When this file is compiled, it could use only a **single set** of compile options. If you want to build libraries with different set of options, you need to create separate targets for them.

Answer (score 1):

This could work with the simple case you've laid out, assuming `lib` is another target created within the same CMake build tree. You could use [`get_target_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_target_property.html) to get the `LINK_LIBRARIES` property list for `TargetA` and `TargetB`. If `lib` is in the list of first-level link dependencies, then you can add the compile definition to `lib`.

```
# Get the list of first-level link dependencies for TargetA and TargetB.
get_target_property(TARGETA_LIBS TargetA LINK_LIBRARIES)
get_target_property(TARGETB_LIBS TargetB LINK_LIBRARIES)

# Loop through the TargetA dependencies.
foreach(LIB ${TARGETA_LIBS})
    # Was the 'lib' library added as a dependency to TargetA?
    if (${LIB} STREQUAL lib)
        # Yes, so add the compile definitions to 'lib'.
        target_compile_definitions(${LIB} PRIVATE DEF_A)
    endif()
endforeach()

# Loop through the TargetB dependencies.
foreach(LIB ${TARGETB_LIBS})
    # Was the 'lib' library added as a dependency to TargetB?
    if (${LIB} STREQUAL lib)
        # Yes, so add the compile definitions to 'lib'.
        target_compile_definitions(${LIB} PRIVATE DEF_B)
    endif()
endforeach()
```

Note, this only works if `lib` is a *first-level* dependency of the target, it does **not** search dependencies recursively, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127212/3987854). Also, if `lib` is an interface library, you'll have to get the [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) property instead.

---

**EDIT** Based on answer feedback: If the compile definitions `DEF_A` and `DEF_B` are mutually exclusive in the `lib` target. The cleanest approach may be to create a separate `lib` target, one catered for `TargetA` and another catered for `TargetB`. This could look something like this:

```
set(LIB_SOURCES 
    Class1.cpp
    ...
)

# Create the 'lib' target to link to TargetA.
add_library(lib_forTargetA SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})
target_compile_definitions(lib_forTargetA PRIVATE DEF_A)

# Create the 'lib' target to link to TargetB.
add_library(lib_forTargetB SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})
target_compile_definitions(lib_forTargetB PRIVATE DEF_B)
```

Comment: But if both TargetA and TargetB link with lib, then this would add both `DEF_A` and `DEF_B` to the lib compile defs? Which is what I am trying to avoid, I do not want lib for target A to have the `DEF_B` definition. Or is `${LIB}` in `${TARGETA_LIBS}` distinct from `${LIB}` in `${TARGETB_LIBS}`?

Comment: @Nick Yes, both `DEF_A` and `DEF_B` would be compile definitions of `lib` in this case. The requirement for them to be mutually exclusive was not clear from your question post... If that's what you want, you would have give one library preference (if A then not B, or if B then not A) so that only `DEF_A` **or** `DEF_B` is added. The other solution is, as suggested, to create separate targets for each case.

Comment: I have updated to make the question clearer. So I think it is best to use a function to create lib targets from the TargetA/B scope.

Comment: @Nick Agreed. This can still be a pretty simple solution; I've expanded my answer to show what that could look like. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. As the library is a third party library and I wanted to do this in a generic way, I defined a function to create a library target with a given name. This way I can specify whatever compile defs I want on the custom target.